# Formatting axis in Surface plot Plotly R

Tags: r, time-series, axis, plotly

Making a 3 month curve for natural gas prices. I'm having some axis issues. I'd like to be able to have the dates show up instead of number of days.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Quandl)
library(magrittr)
require(plotly)

#Get first 3 month on the nat gas curve data from Quandl
my_start_date <- "2013-01-05"

gas1<-Quandl("CHRIS/CME_NG1", start_date = my_start_date, type = "xts")
gas2<-Quandl("CHRIS/CME_NG2", start_date = my_start_date, type = "xts")
gas3<-Quandl("CHRIS/CME_NG3", start_date = my_start_date, type = "xts")

#isolate the last prices
gas1a<-gas1[,"Last"]
gas2a<-gas2[,"Last"]
gas3a<-gas3[,"Last"]

p <- merge(as.zoo(gas1a), as.zoo(gas2a), as.zoo(gas3a), all = FALSE)

#3d graph
plot_ly(z = p, type = "surface")%>%
  layout(title = "3 month Nat Gas curve",
         scene = list(
            xaxis = list(title = "Month"),
            yaxis = list(title = "Days"),
            zaxis = list(title = "Price")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
plot_ly(y=index(p), z = p, type = "surface")%>%
  layout(title = "3 month Nat Gas curve",
         scene = list(
            xaxis = list(title = "Month"),
            yaxis = list(title = "Days", tickangle = 180),
            zaxis = list(title = "Price")))
```

Comment: thats great- how do I angle the text of the dates?

Comment: Great thank you- any idea how I reverse axis labels on x axis? Final one sorry

Comment: we usually add autorange = "reversed" , but it looks like it's not working for 3D plot